# Kernel driver filp_open error

Tags: android

I am trying to use the filp_open function from within the kernel to open a file. I have try open it with "O_RDONLY" flag or "O_RDWR or O_WRONLY", but all can't work.

```
loff_t pos = 0;
mm_segment_t old_fs;
struct file* bmp;

FB_PRINT("[%s] START\n", __func__);

old_fs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
bmp = filp_open("/sdcard/dump_fb.bmp", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0);
if(IS_ERR(bmp)){
    ret = PTR_ERR(bmp);
    printk("[%s] filp_open failed- path[%s], ret[%d]\n",__FUNCTION__, file_path, ret);
    goto ERROR;
}
```

Here is uart log from my android device:

```
[   64.802978] c0 [SaveBMPFile] filp_open failed- path[/sdcard/dump_fb.bmp], ret[-13]
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: EACCES Permission denied

Comment: how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have try others file path, like "/proc", "/system". all would be open failed by "EACCES  13 /* Permission denied */"

Comment: Selinux also disabled for my android device